# TypeScript generic record with given keys

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to validate in TypeScript an object contains the given keys (from `SingleShopColumns` or `MultishopColumns`) and has a `validations` that is an array of strings.

Using Record and generics but any simple way of representing this shape in a generic way would be a valid answer.

```js
export type SingleShopColumns =
  | 'SKU'
  | 'Priority';

export type MultishopColumns =
  | 'Redundant Date'
  | 'Priority';

export type ValidatorSchema<T> = Record<keyof T, { validations: string[] }>;

export const SINGLE_SHOP_SCHEMA: ValidatorSchema<SingleShopColumns> = {
    'SKU': {
        validations: ['validateString']
    },
    'Priority':  {
        validations: ['validateString']
    },
    'Does_not_exist_should be error': {
        validations: ['validateString']
    }
};

export const MULTISHOP_SCHEMA: ValidatorSchema<MultishopColumns> = {
    'Redundant Date': {
        validations: ['validateString']
    },
    'Priority':  {
        validations: ['validateString']
    },
};
```

[TypeScript playground with this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKBLAdgcwDbBoAWEYAwhHgK4C2WAznALwBQccAPnAORoDSAVW5tOPAApQM0DEm4BuFi1CRYCZKgCyVPDAz0S5SrQbMRXbgCVgAEypZrAQyzwAIg5jBh7cxKmTZCkrg0PBIKHAAag54GI4w0GgAxkTANA4APAAqAHzMcFaJ0NbpANbAiBAAZnCZADRwAN5wAG7Rse5SDABccPQwkrgA2gC6cAC%202YHKIXCFDPBoAJIAcgDiADIAogD6aAASAPJiu2R7mxoAgj1RMXEJyakZmLgExKQU1HT0uUyNIuy8QTcHoNf7scGtW4dCDdOCDbiQ9oeND9bA4bjDMFjWpg7i%20aSyHp-cEklptOKdeg9eGIuKEVG4DFYnEk7guCDAejbLAQGDbUB6Pn6CDaaxwABGqGAUCg0GBxNJ7Fp0NhNPJ7npA3RmJJYxYYymwVUcz6cA0AnWmUW%20yOJzOl2u6viUCSKTS6S0Oj0Bg%20xm%20eVBrKstnsTlcGvlgcVZKhuhhVLhCKdmrRTN1LPBeMkBMQ8oViuVcdVSdjKcZOvB2P1ciAA)

Getting an error
`Type '{ SKU: { validations: string[]; }; Priority: { validations: string[]; }; 'Does_not_exist_should be error': { validations: string[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorSchema<SingleShopColumns>'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''SKU'' does not exist in type 'ValidatorSchema<SingleShopColumns>'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is already a key. Remove the `keyof` and add a constraint:

```
export type ValidatorSchema<T extends string> = Record<T, { validations: string[] }>;
```

Comment: Thanks and I don't want all properties can I just wrap it in Partial?
`export type ValidatorSchema<T extends string> = Partial<Record<T, { validations: string[] }>>;`

Comment: @AndréRicardo That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your `T` is aleady an union of keys, thus just

```
export type ValidatorSchema<T extends string|number|symbol> = 
    Record<T, { validations: string[] }>;
```

rather than

```
export type ValidatorSchema<T> = 
    Record<keyof T, { validations: string[] }>;
```